# How to demean only numeric columns in a Pandas dataframe containing categorical variables?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas data frame and wish to demean each of the numeric columns, leaving the categorical variable column entries unchanged. By `"demean"` I simply wish to subtract from each column entry the mean of all entries in the corresponding column.

The data frame comes 569 patients in the `Wisconsin Breast Cancer` directory, listing for each patient 10 various numeric measurements, along with a diagnosis of M (malignant) or B (benign).

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data/UWbcd.csv')
%load_ext google.colab.data_table. #just for purposes of browsing the data
df - df.mean()
```

Using this method, the entries in each numeric column are demeaned fine, but the categorical variables,

```sql
df['Diagnosis']
```

all become NaN.

Is there an efficient way to leave categorical variables alone when demeaning?

Comment: `df.apply(lambda s: s - s.mean() if (s.dtype == np.int or s.dtype == np.float) else s)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like the following, create an array of columns you want to de-mean.

`numerical_cols = ['col1', 'col2', 'col5']`

There you can use loc to only select the columns you want, you can assign this to a new df or back into the current data frame.

`df.loc[:, numerical_cols] = df.loc[:, numerical_cols] - def.loc[:, numerical_cols].mean()`

`df_demean = df.loc[:, numerical_cols] - def.loc[:, numerical_cols].mean()`